ProjectionExpression in AWS queryCommand gives ValidationException using AWS javascript SDK v3
I am writing some test code that accesses DynamoDB through the AWS javascript SDK v3.
I have a simple table called Projects with UserId as the Partition key and Name as the Sort Key.
The only other attribute is named Data.  Data can be a large string.
I need to be able to get the list of Names for a given UserId, without getting Data for all of the items.
I am writing some test code just to see how this might work.  I am using the queryCommand to try to get the list of the Name field values for the given UserId.
Here is my test code:
    $("#getProjectsButton").on("click", function(event){
        var dbProjectsPromise = window.gridAWSFunctions.queryCommand(window.dbData.clientDB, {
            "TableName": "Projects",
            "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
                ":v1": {
                    "S": window.authData.identity.id
                }
            },
            "KeyConditionExpression": "UserId = :v1",
            //"Select": "SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES",
            //"ProjectionExpression": "Name",
            "ConsistentRead": true
        });
        dbProjectsPromise.then(function(dbResponse){
            console.log(dbResponse);
        })
    });

window.gridAWSFunctions = {
    queryCommand: async function(client, input){
        const command = new QueryCommand(input);
        const response = await client.send(command);
        return response;
    }
}

When I run the code above it works correctly, and I get a list of Items and it has both the Name and the Data attributes in it.
When I uncomment out the "ProjectionExpression":"Name" line, then I get a ValidationException.
Same thing if I uncomment out both the "Select" and the "ProjectionExpression" together.
Examples I see only have the "ProjectionExpression", so I would expect that to work without the "Select" key.
Do I need something else in here?  What am I missing.  I don't see anything else in other examples I have looked at.
I also tried putting the "Data" value in place of name in the ProjectionExpression, but it also gives ValidationException.
I also tried creating an index on the UserId and projecting the Name field into it.  I added Query access to my IAM policy (which got past an authorization denied message).  I ran the query against the index without the ProjectionExpression in it and got a ValidationException.  So, something was wrong there.  I would rather not have to have the index to do this.
What am I doing wrong?
Alternately, is there another way for me to do this?

I am literally looking at an example that should be exactly the same thing I am trying to do.  This is at:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/dynamodb/command/QueryCommand/, see the Example Usage section.  I don't see anything different that I am doing.

I have already found the answer!!
And the answer is that Name and Data are reserved words.
Deleted the table and am now using UserId, ProjectName and ProjectData.
Now the code works with the ProjectionExpression set to "ProjectName"!
